# Linux command to extract the value for a given name

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Suppose I have one text file(`EmployeeDetails.txt`) in which the content is written(all name/value in new line) as mentioned below:-

```
EmployeeName=XYZ
EmployeeBand=D5
EmployeeDesignation=SSE
```

I need the Linux command which will read this file `EmployeeDetails.txt` and give the value for `EmployeeBand`. Output should be

`D5`

Comment: If any of the following answer helped you in your goal please accept/upvote the answer for closure by ticking right sign besides the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep`: If anything is followed by `EmployeeBand=` will be printed.

```
grep -oP 'EmployeeBand=\K.*' EmployeeDetails.txt
```

Using `awk` where `=` is used as field separator and second field is printed. if search criteria is meet.

```
awk -F'=' '/EmployeeBand/{print $2}' EmployeeDetails.txt
```

Using `sed` ,here the band `D5` is captured is a group inside `()` and later used using `\1`.

```
sed -r '/EmployeeBand/ s/.*=(.*$)/\1/g' EmployeeDetails.txt
```